# Git Push fails and returns 403 in Windows

Tags: windows, git, push, gogs

Environment

- client : Windows
- server : Gogs

I'd like to push some sources to git repository.

But there are some problems to push it.

Error message is below :

```
D:\workspace\excel-demo>git push -u origin master Counting objects:
42, done. Delta compression using up to 8 threads. Compressing
objects: 100% (28/28), done. Writing objects: 100% (42/42), 50.75 KiB
| 2.82 MiB/s, done. Total 42 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0) error: RPC
failed; HTTP 403 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 403
Forbidden fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal: The remote
end hung up unexpectedly Everything up-to-date
```

I was set up credential in remote information like `test@~~~~/~~~.git`

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

`test@~~~~/~~~.git` is not a "credential" (login/password), but an SSH URL which means: connect to the remote server as user 'test', and use `~~~.git` as a remote Git repository destination.

That supposes you have an SSH key pair in your %USERPROFILE%.ssh.
And that the public key (id_rsa.pub) was registered on the remote server in `~test/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

If that is not the case, you need to check how the remote server expects you to authenticate (username/password? SSH key?)

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought i may be `-u` option ad `master` will already be set up, but you would get a nice git message.

I think you may not have write access or your credentials are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :**git push origin master**
Then it will ask for password. Enter your proper credentials and hope it works. If nothing works. Delete your repository and make a fresh push.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a new Collaborator. On GOGs access the repository and go to 'Settings' > 'Collaboration' > [add a valid GOGs login name] > click on 'Add New Collaborator'. After that (at least for me) the push was successful!